# How to retrieve links posted by third-party Facebook apps?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to build an app that fetch all the links posted on a Facebook page. I'll use the Kotaku page as an example (`https://www.facebook.com/kotaku`, Facebook ID is `273824104039`).

I have tried to get the links via the graph API (`https://graph.facebook.com/273824104039`) or via FQL (here is the query I used: `SELECT link_id, owner,  title, url, owner_comment, summary, created_time FROM link WHERE owner = 273824104039`), but both of them only return a subset of the links posted (20 as of writing this post).

(All request were made with an access token from my account that I granted the read_stream permission. I also 'like' the Kotaku page, but according to the documentation the `links` connection is available to everyone on Facebook.)

If you go on the page,  it's pretty obvious that there are more than 20 links, but most of these were posted via the dlvr.it app and those are not showing in the queries above.

So does anyone know it there is a way to get those links as well? If possible, I would like to get all the links posted on that page not just the last 50 or from the last 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that links posted by apps aren't treated as native Facebook links, they're just posts with attachments, so you're not likely to find anything in `links`. With that said, try looking at the `stream` FQL table or the [`posts` parameter of the graph](http://graph.facebook.com/273824104039/posts).

Comment: I did look into those, but sadly the feed connection also contains the post made by other user on the page wall, which add a lot of data more data to process.

As for the stream table I wasn't able to get a stream_filter for the page, only for myself, so I get the same problem as /feed

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to say `/posts`, give that a shot. I've updated my answer with the link.